# Cannot access vagrant MySQL database from outside (only when vagrant ssh'd into the box w/Scotchbox)

Tags: mysql, vagrant, remote-connection

I am running Vagrant & Virtual Box - I have a PHP/MySQL setup within my Vagrantfile when I `vagrant ssh` via the terminal I can access my database directly without any issue using the default root user (password is 'root')

My Vagrant IP is `192.168.33.1` and I have added this to my hosts file to map to `dev.myworkspace.com`

When I run the following command to access the `mysql -h dev.myworkspace.com -u root -p` & enter the correct password (root) it returns the following error:

`ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'192.168.33.1' (using password: YES)`

I have tried adding `bind-address = 0.0.0.0` to the my.cnf file within the vagrant box but when I restart mysql it hangs.

Can anyone explain what I am doing wrong? I just want to be able to connect to my vagrant MySQL database albeit from outside `vagrant ssh` (so need to allow external connections)

NOTE - the root user has been setup as the follows:
`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looks that the permission for user root are only set to **localhost**

Try this to queries. If the second gives no result try the **update** and **flush*

```
SHOW GRANTS FOR  'root'@'localhost';
SHOW GRANTS FOR  'root'@'%';

UPDATE mysql.user
SET Host='%' WHERE Host='localhost' AND User='root';

FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Comment: Thanks for that Bernd - I am getting : 
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION |
| GRANT PROXY ON ''@'' TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION

and 

| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' |

When i run the UPDATE command you added I get the following error: 
ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '%-root' for key 'PRIMARY'

Comment: @Zabs - can you please see if all passwords are the same from user **root** like **select Host,User,Password from mysql.user where user='root';**